# NOT able to store data in database in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am a learner in YII. I cant store the values in the datatbase, pls help me in this. I must store the values in the product table. the values are fetched but it is not stored in the DB. Thank you in advance
Controller:

```
<?php

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new CreateForm;
    // collect user input data
        if(isset($_POST['CreateForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['CreateForm'];
                        if($model->validate())
                        {
                           echo "HI";

                        }


        }
        // display the login form
        $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model));


    }
}
?>
```

Model:

```
<?php

class CreateForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $product_name;
    public $category_name;
    public $description;

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'products';
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('product_name, category_name, description', 'required'),
           array('product_name', 'unique', 'className' => 'Product', 'attributeName' => 'product_name', 'message'=>'This product name is already in use'),
    array('product_name,category_name,desc', 'safe'),   
            );

    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'product_name'=>'PRODUCT NAME',
                    'category_name'=>'CATEGORY',
                    'description'=>'DESCRIPTION'
        );
    }



}
?>
```

view:

```
<?php
$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Create';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Create',
);
?>

<h1>CREATE</h1>
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'create-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,

)); 

?>


    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'product_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'product_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'product_name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <?php
             echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_name');   
                $records = Category::model()->findAll();
               $list = CHtml::listData($records, 'category_id', 'category_name');
               echo $form->dropDownList($model,'category_name',$list,array ('prompt'=>'select '));
               echo $form->error($model,'category_name');
                ?>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'description'); ?></br>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'description',array('style' => 'height:100px;width:500px;','maxlength'=>500)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'description'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row submit">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('CREATE'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

Comment: ps:always use validate() and save() methods when inserting data; if you get in trouble when validating, use within the model a beforeSave() method and the die('here') method in order to see the values stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if($model->validate())
 {
      if(!$model->save()) // save it here!
      {
           // do stuff after successful save
      }
 }
```

UPDATE:

`CFormModel` does not have method save()

you need to extend your model from `CActiveRecord`

```
function saveInDb()
{
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand(); // create a sql command and do insert here
    .
    . 
    .
}
```

Comment: I tried it in controller. but it says "Property "CreateForm.save" is not defined."

Comment: CFormModel does not have method save()

Comment: the following error occurs "CreateForm and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "save"."

Comment: how to call the function tat I have defined in CForm Model class??

Comment: in the function how to save in DB?

Comment: Updated my post, do something like that,

Comment: its not about echo-ing statements, the main concept is to store in DB. i have called the function, but inside the function how to save it in DB?

Comment: in there you have your sql command, ready to be executed, just fill whatever you need in that command and execute it,I'm not spoon feeding the answer to you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
if($model->validate())
{
   $model->save();
}
```

?

well, first of all, tf this is supposed to be a form based on table data you need to extend not from CFormModel but from CActiveRecord.
second:
for better readability and portability rewrite your tableName method

```
public function tableName()
    {
        return '{{products}}';
    }
```

Comment: I tried it in controller, but it displays "CreateForm and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "save"."

Answer (score 1):

Try This, Save function auto call validate form.

```
if($model->save()){
      echo 'add record success'.
}
else {
      echo 'failed'.
}
```